# HTML Trouble putting in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document where it goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- some title, meta stuff and css -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <style src="/secondvid.js"></style>
    <div id="vid1"></div>
    <button onclick="showSecondVid('vid1', 'vid2');">Video 2</button>
    <div id="vid2" style="display: none;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is inside the divs is not important, but the script looks like this:

```
function showSecondVid(vid1Id, vid2Id) {
  document.getElementById(vid1Id).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById(vid2Id).style.display = "block";
  document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].style.display = "none";
  dayUp();
}
function dayUp() {
  if (localStorage.dayFinished === 4) {
    localStorage.dayFinished = 0;
  } else if (localStorage.dayFinished) {
    localStorage.dayFinished++;
  }
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. Can someone help?
I want the first div to disappear and the second one to appear.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you include your JS with a `<script>` tag instead of a `<style>`.

Comment: As others have already noted, you include JavaScript code or files in <script> tags and you include CSS with <style> tags. It’s good practice to include script files, as you’ve done, and not write inline JavaScript code. Sorry other SO users downvoted you. It’s okay to be new to software development. Keep working hard. You might try the SO chat rooms, which are more informal, and perhaps more forgiving while learning the basics. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call your script like this :

```
<script src="/secondvid.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<style src="/secondvid.js"></style>
```